# How to render inside a webview specific divs from a Website using android java

Tags: java, android

In this test what I'm trying to do is, theres a website with a game on it and I want to render only that div, the site itself already renders well. I tried to manipulate the content after was loaded and still didn't work, it renders the whole content.

The game itself renders inside that block of code :

[image]

Then I just :

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.game);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.escolagames.com.br/jogos/forma-palavras");
```

Comment: is the url your own website? Also, have you set up a javascript bridge to communicate between the webview and the application?

Comment: Its not mine, I tried that but, I don't know how to get that div and exclude the rest of it, or just hide the entire webview and leave only the game. I'm trying to concentrate some games to my kid to use, but I didn't want to him to click in other menus or url from the browser.

Comment: Then you won't be able to do what you are after in this way.